# Rotating a camera around a still ball (mini golf aiming)

Tags: game-engine, camera

I'm making a mini golf game and I'm completely finished apart from this one detail. Once the ball is shot I want to be able to rotate the camera around the ball to see the hole, but right now the camera is stuck on a single axis right behind the ball. I used [this](http://www.blendenzo.com/tutVertexParenting.html) method to parent the camera to the ball to eliminate camera roll.

I'm not looking for a 360 animation, just to be able to reposition the camera while maintaining centering on the ball

Here's my blend file if you want to take a look!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxB2pKMjGzzqT3dldXVhZkZkTkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: vertex parent an empty to the ball, parent the camera to the empty, and have your rotation controls on the empty?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a second camera and just switch cameras . The second camera would have a "Track To" constraint so it will be looking where you want it to and you can position it or animate it as needed. You can use an empty as the target and have more flexibility if needed.